# Playing video (OGG Theora) in a C# WinForms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, video, vlc, ogg

I'm looking for a GPL-compatible solution for playing a video file in a Windows Forms control, specifically with the OGG Theora codec?

I was looking into using the [VLC player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player#Use_of_VLC_with_other_programs) library.  A Google search found [this library on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/LiquidVideo.aspx), but it was apparently deleted.

Is there a mirror or a similar library available?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [MOGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org/wiki/index.php/MOGRE) (such cute names), you could also build [the source](http://www.theora.org/downloads/) and do the interop by hand, but the wrapper is probably better.

Comment: Including a whole 3D rendering engine seems like overkill just to playback a .ogg file.

Answer (score 0):

have you seen [vlcdotnet](http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/) ?